# FireBase - Two devices should be triggered at the same time

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-security

For the last couple of days i'm stuck with what i call, overthinking :

FireBase is dedicated to be a "Real Time" communication platform. I'm trying to understand what is the right approach for the follow up situation.
In my PVP game, two users suppose to start the game at the same time. I'm already making a "pre check" to make this two events as close as possible(promote both of the users to click a button, observe specific value change, and only than start).
**Yet**, both of them starting with a small delay of 1-2 sec.

**Even tho FireBase suppose to act as a "Real Time" platform, should i assume(/code) within this perspective?** Or should i assume Delay is going to be a common issue?

**2. Is there an avg delay/time, assuming FireBase works as he should and my code is efficient, for each listenValue "call"?**

**UPDATE**

**NOTE* Each user "listen" to the other device "ready" state, so when the "last" device click ready, the game will automatically start**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since as there is a small delay between player sync. Which I think I because when you attach your second player to the game it triggers must be starting the game as soon as second player is registered. I think you need a small delay between adding your second player to the game and starting the game. Posting some code might help a little more to understand the exact problem.

Comment: Hey Taj. Thanks for your respond. What's B/W btw? I will add an describing image

Comment: My appologies i mean between two players

Comment: Thats fine haha. Thanks. Added image

Comment: Hi Roi are you sending the second player ready state and start game one after the other?

Comment: No. It's actually quiet straightforward. Both of the devices listen to each other "ready" property. If i clicked ready first, The other user notify about this, so when he clicks "ready" i listen to this changes as well. I'm already ready + he know's it. So the game automatically start. But still - there is a small delay(which in my specific game create kind of bad game experience)

Comment: Then i think the time gap lies where you have received the second player ready state and started the game on your side but the other player is waiting for you confirmation to start the game which would take as much time as it would take to travel through network. Which seems to be increasing on weak network.

Comment: Thats make sense. But even if i would make sure that i'll start play AFTER  i checked that the user got already notify(some how). I would still have 1 user that will start before the other - when the gap is 1 network call. Arg, What would you do?

Comment: in such situation i would rather have a game server to handle and manage to send events(register player/start game) at the same time

Comment: Actually FB has their security rules which suppose to help you - but there is no server side..

Comment: Right now a way to solve this can be adding one more event to start a game like
`yourapp.firebaseapp.com/game/gamename/start`
listen to the event and whenever your second players join post start event . This way all of players will be notified at once.
hope this solves your problem.